# Limit deletion in ContentEditable contents

Tags: html, contenteditable

How could we prevent user from deleting some tags like **links** from editable elements? Is there another way than splitting paragraph to spans and distribute **contenteditable="true"** attribute over them?

```
<p id="content" contenteditable="true">
   Some text here.
   <a href='my_link_1'>click here</a>
   another text here  
   <a href='my_link_2'>click here</a>
   thank you. 
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this issue:
Splitting contents to sup-element and then apply **Contenteditable** attribute for what we need to be editable only.
 After user has accomplished his editing we can simply re-assumable this parts again.

```
<p id="content">
   <span contenteditable="true">Some text here.</span>
   <a href='my_link_1'>click here</a>
   <span contenteditable="true">another text here</span>
   <a href='my_link_2'>click here</a>
   <span contenteditable="true">thank you.</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use span tags with content set within them in CSS. They're slightly less deletable if you catch my drift, but hey at least if one character is deleted the entire thing is deleted.

```html
<style>
.uneditable:before {
    content: "can't touch this";
}
</style>

<p id="content" contenteditable="true">
Some text here.
<span class="uneditable"></span>
 another text here  
</p>
```